# Authorize subdomain to access and read user and admin cookies

Tags: admin, cookies, subdomains, https, session

My subdomains redirect alls in the main domain .
I am the admin.
We can access to my website by the main domain or subdomain.
I use that to share cookies between domain and subdomain :
There is no difference if I let empty ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIEPATH, and SITECOOKIEPATH.

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('COOKIEPATH', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Currently all subdomains have access to same cookies as main domain but they can't read these.

I read in other stackoverflow post that I must add a period cookie.
But the main domain doesn't need a period to be allowed to read cookies !
The wordpress_test_cookie has the same value in domain and subdomain .
the cookies set on domain and subdomain : wordpress_logged_in_, wordpress_sec_, wordpress_test_cookie and wp_lang.

This function `wp_get_current_user()` doesn't return user informations on subdomain but well return for main domain.

More information :
I defined WP_HOME depending of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'):
 `switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) { case 'suddom.website.com': define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://suddom1.website.com/' ); break; case 'visiter.activus.city': define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://suddom2.website.com/' ); break; case 'habiter.activus.city': define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://suddom3.website.com/' ); break; default: define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://website.com/' ); } define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);`

can this cause a problem to allow wordpress to authorize subdomain to access and read user informations ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem using that: (edited

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/wp-admin');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.website.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '.website.com');
define('COOKIEHASH', md5('website.com') );`
```

COOKIEHASH is essential